# Yii2 Read PHPExcel from specific file path

Tags: file, path, yii2, phpexcel

I'm using Yii2 framework (advanced template) to read some data from Excel file.
In my code, I define a full path of the file in directory D with test.xls name:

```
public function actionReadExcel()
{
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('D:/test.xls');

    $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A1:A10');

    foreach ($sheetData as $val){
        echo $val[0];
    }
}
```

That way I manually defined the path in code, how can I make a user to input specific file path from the view or web interface?
something like browse path or browse file.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

That would only be usefull when the user is on the same machine - the file has to be in the local file system (or somewhere in the cloud) to be read by your application.

If you want to read files from the computer of the enduser, which is not on your machine, you've got to make an upload form, let the user upload the excel file to your server and process it once that is complete. Yii has an excellent guide for this:

[File uploading](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 have nice system of aliases: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/667/yii-2-list-of-path-aliases-available-with-default-basic-and-advanced-app/

If You upload XML file via FTP or any other method, You can do something like

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('@web/upload/test.xls');
```